# Java REST, failed loading POST

Tags: javascript, java, http, rest

Всем привет! Вообщем есть веб сайт, и есть Ресть веб сервис. При авторизации юзера, отправляется запрос на сервер по ссылке и все. Локально все работало когда запускал его на WildFly 11, НО как только сделал деплой на Хероку, так сразу все сломалось. Все загружается корректно, все изображения, стили, скрипты. Но рест не работает.

Вот это то что я получаю на странице сайта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это сам метод к которому я обращаюсь из кода JavaScript:

Comment: Может ты забыл добавить контекст приложения к адресу, который равен его имени? Во всяком случае тебе точно стоит посмотреть логи сервера.

Comment: @Темкатоже, все дело в том, что этот код работает у меня локально, я делаю все тоже самое только с помощью веб сервера "WildFly". В логах есть только то, что при обращению к адрессу, он возвращает ошибку 404.

Comment: Как называется твоё web-приложение, другими словами, в какой war'ник собирается твоё приложение?

Comment: Я думаю проблема не в этом. Потому что локально у меня все работает, но когда делаю деплой на Heroku, то оно перестает работать.